# Remove footers from googleVis output

Tags: r, googlevis

Is there a way to remove or hide the footer from the `googleVis` output? Here is what shows up in every `googleVis` output.

> Data: sport • Chart ID: TimelineID95891e64f3 • googleVis-0.5.10
>   R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) • Google Terms of Use • Documentation and Data Policy

Answer (score 2):

create your visualization

```
M <- gvisColumnChart(data, xvar = "", yvar = "", options = list(), chartid)
```

then remove the footers and captions

```
M$html$footer <- NULL
M$html$jsFooter <- NULL
M$html$caption <- NULL
```

then print or plot the chart

```
print(M,tag = "html" ,file = "M.html") 
plot(M)
```

Comment: Is this legal? https://developers.google.com/terms/ See prohibits: 9. Remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms. 
I mean it's still in the source code comment, but I am not sure if it's ok to remove this ugly looking caption / footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the **jsFooter** by setting a global option. Here I have set the the **plot.tag** to *chart* and **jsFooter** to *NULL* which removes the footer entirely.

```
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag="chart", jsFooter=NULL)
```

Use `getOption("gvis.tags")` to see a list of additional tags you can customize.